# $H^{n}(M)$ where $M$ is compact, orientable and connected manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I need to show that if $M$ is compact, orientable and connected manifold of dimension $n$, then $H^{n}(M) = \mathbb{R}$. 
I saw that a possible proof is to take an atlas for $M$, with $U_{\alpha}$, $\alpha = 1,..N$ and $\rho_{\alpha}$ be a smooth partition of unity. Then define a smooth map 
\begin{equation}
\xi: \Omega^{n}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}
\end{equation}
by 
\begin{equation}
\xi(\omega) = (\int_{M}\rho_1\omega,..,\int_{M}\rho_N\omega)
\end{equation}
and consider the subspace $X = \{\xi(dv) | v \in \Omega^{n-1}(M)\}$.
The proof than shows that (proof is omitted)

(A) $\omega$ is exact if and only if $\xi(\omega) \in X$

(B) $w \in \Omega^{n}(M)$ is exact if and only if $\int_M\omega=0$.

I have two questions:

1) What does it means $\omega$ is exact? It's not a sequence, just an element of $\Omega^{n}(M)$.
2) Why (B) actually implies that $H^{n}(M) = \mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. A differential $n$-form $\alpha$ is exact if there is some differential $(n-1)$-form $\beta$ such that $d\beta = \alpha$.
2. Recall that $H^n(M)$ is defined by taking the closed $n$-forms and modding out by the exact $n$-forms. Fact (B) implies that integration gives you a well-defined map $H^n(M)\rightarrow \mathbb R$, since any exact form integrates to zero. In fact, you can show that this is a vector space isomorphism. (Hint: Take a non-zero closed form $\alpha$ and show that any other closed form is equivalent, modulo some exact form, to a multiple of $\alpha$. Use the integration map.)

(Note that part $B$ follows from Stokes's theorem.)

Comment: Can you please give me additional hint why $H^{n}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in case any exact form integrates to zero? Did i missed some definition or some obvious fact?

Comment: @cactus You need to show that integration gives the same number regardless of which representative of a fixed cohomology class you choose. But, by definition of de Rham cohomology, all representatives differ from each other by some exact form. So their difference integrates to zero, and every representative gives the number when integrated.

Comment: If i take some element $w \in H^{n}(M)$, than $w = w_{1} + w_{2}$, where $w_{1}$ is closed $n$-form and $w_{2}$ is exact. So integrating it gives $\int_{M}w = \int_{M}w_{1}$, so why it means that $w$ is constant?

Comment: @cactus Look up the definition of $H^n$ again. Elements of $H^n$ are equivalence classes of forms, not forms.

Comment: Right, elements of $H^{n}(M)$ are $[\omega]=\{ \omega + d\eta , \eta \in \Omega^{n-1}(M) \}$. But i still do not follow why $H^{n}(M) = \mathbb{R}$ if integration of exact forms is 0.

Comment: @cactus Fix some form $\alpha$ that has nonzero integral. We may assume by scaling that $\int_M \alpha =1$. Then if $[\beta]$ is some element of $H^n$ with $\int \beta = c$, $\int c\alpha -\beta =0$, so $\beta-c\alpha$ is exact and $[\beta]=[c\alpha]$. Hence $\alpha$ generates $H^n$ and $H^n\cong\mathbb R$.